# How to enable freestyle edges on top of freestyle faces?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, faces, edges, freestyle

Using blender render and freestyle lines I used "control- e" to set some freestyle edges to render, they render fine and all, however the mesh is animated and moves so it sometimes also renders freestyle lines set by the "edge types" under "freestyle line set" in "render layers".

I dont want these automatic lines in some spots so that is where "control-f" freestyle faces come in so that no lines render on those faces. The problem is that it also cancels out the freestyle edges I set with "control-e" and they dont render.

Is there a way to set freestyle faces and freestyle edges so that the edges I set render, while the freestyle face blocks the automatic lines at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to get it perfectly, but you can set freestyle to only render edges specified as "freestyle edge", like this

[image]

if you use face marks (here in blue)

[image]

you can use it to (eg) exclude some parts of the previously marked edges (also blue to make them more visible):

[image]

Comment: Right I get that part, but the problem is I want to enable silhoutte, border, contour, etc. and then block out specific areas where I dont want to enable that. For example if I have two blocks and on one of them, everything is enabled but for the other only edge marks are enabled. Which is why I tried to do edge marks on top of face marks (to disable the other options and only leave edge marks to render).

Comment: It's too complicated to understand just with words, I fear:try to create a small test case, easy to understand and share it here through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then insert the provided link editing your question, and also add an image of what is wrong when you try the setup as in the file...